# how to implement a protocol adapter

Tags: c++, sockets, protocols, message-queue, opc

I want to implement a adapter which can provide a universal interface to clients to use socket, opc, message queue, etc. In other words, it is a non-trivial job to learn to use the three above protocols' api.

For example, the client want to communicate with a external socket server, and the only thing he should do is to use our simple api rather than the complex bsd-socket's.

I want to know is there any existing implementation now which I can learn from. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ZeroMQ provides a socket like API that allows you to abstract away the transport mechanism.  Currently it supports in process, shared memory, PGM, and TCP as transport mechanisms.

Answer (score -1):

Google has protobuf, i think it's called, and there is another i've seen mentioned but it escapes me at the moment. [Check here for information on protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Comment: thanks! maybe i didn't explain it clearly. here is the scene: there is a socket server which has defined a specific communication format such as xml.  i want to implement a middleware which can not only provide a more simple api than bsd-socket, but also deal with the xml-formated message transformation. so the architecture looks like "app----middleware---socket server"(sorry, i don't know how to insert a photo). the other two protocols also work in this way.